# How to find the upper bound of symmetric triangle distribution given median and lower bound

Tags: distributions

I have been told $x$ is drawn from a symmetric triangle distribution. 
If the lower bound is 3 and the median is 9, how do I calculate the upper bound?

I'm not sure which value to use (I have to substitute the value I find into a formula). I was thinking if perhaps I had the upper bound, lower bound and median. I could work out the mean and use the mean value?

Comment: Hi there & welcome to cross validated. I've edited your post, please check it looks ok. Can you please add the [self-study tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) if this is homework?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/713528/15941)

Comment: Can you tell us what you think the word "symmetry" means in this context?

Comment: @DilipSarwate in that case should I delete my answer? I'm not sure what the correct protocol is when questions are cross-posted.

Comment: @Amy2014 please see [this article re cross-posting](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/stackexchange-mathematics-vs-cross-validated).

Comment: @TooTone I seem to remember that on SE sites once an Answer has been Accepted, it can no longer be deleted by the author of the answer. Perhaps asking the Moderators for the correct protocol is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you've been given:

[image]

You know the lower bound is 3, and you know it's a triangle distribution so it increases from 3 towards the median at 9. At some point it starts to decrease again, either before, at, or after the median.

The median is the value of $x$ such that the probability of drawing a value less than the median is 50%. Pictorially this means that exactly half of the area under the triangle must lie between the lower bound and the median.

You're also told that the distribution is symmetric. What this means in the case of the triangle distribution is that you must be able to draw a vertical line through the highest point of the distribution such that the distribution to the left is a mirror image of the distribution to the right.

Hopefully this is enough information to let you find the answer for yourself.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, Im still somewhat confused.

Comment: ok, if you can be more specific hopefully I can help (and you might not want to accept my answer until you're satisfied that my answer works for you).

Comment: I believe the upper bound is 16. What is the triangular distribution used for in the world ? im just trying to find how it is applied in the real world, so I make more sense of what value to use in my question.

Comment: I don't get 16. With 16 you're close but no cigar!. Can you think how to complete drawing the triangle so it looks symmetric? Draw it on paper with a ruler if you need to to get the distances correct, ideally on graph paper if you can. (Re practical uses, the triangle distribution arises naturally as the sum of two uniform variables -- see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Related_distributions), or [think rolling two dice](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/dice.html).)